# There are 100 prizes, with one worth 1 dollar, one worth 2 dollars,. . . ,

Tags: probability

There are 100 prizes, with one worth 1 dollar, one worth 2 dollars,. . . , and one worth 100 dollars. There are 100 boxes, each of which contains one of the prizes. You get 5 prizes by picking random boxes one at a time, without replacement. Find the PMF of how much your most valuable prize is worth (as a simple expression in terms of binomial coefficients).

- In class the correct answer was said to be $P(X=x)$=$\binom{x-1}{4}$/$\binom{100}{5}$ and I know where the $\binom{100}{5}$ came from because there are 100 prices and you can choose 5 but I am confused as to where the $\binom{x-1}{4}$ is coming from. All I have in my notes is that he said when a max of 5 is x then 4 can be chosen but that makes no sense to me. Can someone please help me understand the thought process behind $\binom{x-1}{4}$, it would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We want to count the sets $\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,x\}$ of $5$ prizes in which $x$ is the most valuable prize. For that to be the case $p_1,p_2,p_3$, and $p_4$ must be $4$ different prizes each worth less than $x$. In fact there is one such set for each set $\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\}$ of $4$ prizes with values less than $x$. Those values can be any whole number of dollars between $1$ and $x-1$ inclusive, so in effect we are simply choosing $4$ integers from the set $\{1,2,\ldots,x-1\}$ to be the lesser prizes, and there are $\binom{x-1}4$ ways to do that. Thus, there are $\binom{x-1}4$ sets of $5$ prizes in which $x$ is the most valuable prize.

Answer (score 1):

Brian's answer is correct, but I just wanted to try and provide an alternative point of view.
You have $100$ boxes where the price of box $i$ is $i$. The experiment consists in picking $5$ boxes at random and the random variable $X$ is the maximum price you get after picking those $5$ boxes.

First, remark that for $1\leq i\leq 4$, $P(X=i) = 0$, because since you are picking $5$ boxes, the "smallest" sequence you can get is $1-2-3-4-5$ in any order.

Now, for $5\leq i \leq 100$, let us consider the case of $i=5$, so we are looking for $P(X=5)$. There is only one sequence that can satisfy that event, i.e., $1-2-3-4-5$ so you have $P(X=5) = \frac{1}{\binom{100}{5}} = \frac{\binom{5-1}{4}}{\binom{100}{5}}$

The reason we have $\binom{5-1}{4}$ as the numerator of $P(X=5)$ might not be clear yet, so let us consider the event $P(X=6)$. For this, you need $6$ to be your largest number in the sequence you obtain after picking the $5$ boxes. Hence, we can imagine that we have fixed the value of the first box to be $6$, and we want that to be the max. For that to happen, we need the remaining 4 boxes to take any values in the set $\{5,4,3,2,1\}$, so we 5-choose-4 choice which is $\binom{6-1}{4}$.

If you keep going, we get $P(X=i) = \frac{\binom{i-1}{4}}{\binom{100}{5}}$ for $i\in\{5,6,\dots,100\}$

Note, $\sum_{i=5}^{100} \frac{\binom{i-1}{4}}{\binom{100}{5}} = 1$. Hence, the above function is a valid PMF.